# Can I get more RAM in emulator while still having a Google Play image?

Tags: android-emulator, avd-manager

I know how to make a new system image, by cloning an existing one...

But, I can't alter the amount of RAM in a Google Play-enabled image, without the clone being non-Google Play.

Is there a way to give more RAM to the image while keeping it Google Play-able, instead of the default 1.5GB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UI does not allow to change the RAM size neither when creating a new virtual device nor later when editing the virtual device.

However on file level you can simply open the configuration file of the AVD and change the RAM size.

Use an text editor and open `~/.android/avd/<avd name>.avd/config.ini`.

Search for the line

```
hw.ramSize = 1536
```

and change the amount of RAM, for example to

```
hw.ramSize = 4096
```

Then boot the virtual device and you will have 4096 MB RAM as shown in this screenshot:

[image]